# JavaScript String test with array of RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some doubts regarding RegEx in JavaScript as I am not good in RegEx.

I have a String and I want to compare it against some array of RegEx expressions.

First I tried for one RegEx and it's not working. I want to fix that also.

```
function check(str){
var regEx = new RegEx("(users)\/[\w|\W]*");
var result = regEx.test(str);
if(result){
//do something
}
}
```

It is not working properly.
If I pass ***users***, it doesn't match. If I pass **users/** or **users/somestring**, it is matching.

If I change the RegEx to **(usersGroupList)[/\w|\W]***, then it is matching for any string that contains the string users

*fdgdsfgg**userslist/data***

I want to match like if string is either *users* or it should contain *users/something* or *users/*

And also I want the string to compare it with similar regex array.

I want to compare the string *str* with *users*, *users/something*, *list*, *list/something*, *anothermatch*, *anothermatch/something*. If if it matches any of these expression i want to do something.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest what is your thinking behind `[\w|\W]*`? These cancel each other out, so this will in fact match _everything_, including other `/`s. If that is what you want then just use `.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about making:

1. the last group optional
2. starting from beginning of the string

Like this:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^(users)(\/[\w|\W]*)?");
```

Same applies for all the others cases, e.g. for `list`:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^(list)(\/[\w|\W]*)?");
```

### All in One Approach

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^(users|list|anothermatch)(\/[\w|\W]*)?");
```

### Even More Generic

```
var keyw = ["users", "list", "anothermatch"];
var keyws = keyw.join("|"); 
var regEx = new RegExp("^("+keyws+")(\/[\w|\W]*)?");
```

Comment: Can I create array of RegEx expressions and test?

Comment: You can do all at once listing the keywords in a group with | (or) condition.

Answer (score 2):

Then, you'll have to make the last group optional. You do that by capturing the /something part in a group and following it with `?` which makes the previous token, here the captured group, optional.

```
var regEx = new RegExp("(users)(\/[\w|\W]*)?");
```

Comment: Cool. It worked for one. How can I do for An Array of expressions? Do I need to loop and create RegEx objects and match??

Comment: This **1.** does not cover array of keys **2.** matches spurious beginning of the string (e.g. `"fdgdsfgguserslist/data"`)

Comment: @TGMCians just another one please

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made the / optional. Try this instead

```
(users)\/?[\w|\W]*
```

Comment: this will match `usersfhkfhsfd`